# what is the best way to use eigen::matrix multiplication in tensorflow? Convert the tensor to matrix, then convert it back?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, eigen3, tensor

I want to add a new op in c++ in tensorflow. And I want to apply matrix multiplication to tensor. I convert the tensor to Eigen::matrix to get the product, then I convert it back to tensor.

```
EigenTensor<float> Mh_chip = Tmh.chip(i, 0);
EigenTensor<float> h_chip = Th.chip(i, 0);
auto Mh = EigenMatrixMap<float>(Mh_chip.data(), Mh_chip.dimension(0), Mh_chip.dimension(1));
auto h = EigenMatrixMap<float>(h_chip.data(), h_chip.dimension(0), h_chip.dimension(1));
EigenMatrix<float> h_p = Mh * h;
Th_p.chip(i, 0) = EigenTensorMap<float>(h_p.data(), h_chip.dimensions());
```

Write code like this is painful. Any advice?

Comment: Put it in a function?

Comment: @HenriMenke Maybe you are right. Thanks!